# Spark - pass full row to a udf and then get column name inside udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark with Scala and want to pass the entire row to udf and select for each column name and column value in side udf. How can I do this?

I am trying following -

```
inputDataDF.withColumn("errorField", mapCategory(ruleForNullValidation) (col(_*)))

def mapCategory(categories: Map[String, Boolean]) = {
  udf((input:Row) =>  //write a recursive function to check if each row is in categories if yes check for null if null then false, repeat this for all columns and then combine results)   
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spark 1.6 you can use `Row` as external type and `struct`  as expression. as expression. Column name can be fetched from the schema. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct}

val df = Seq((1, 2, 3)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
val f = udf((row: Row) => row.schema.fieldNames)
df.select(f(struct(df.columns map col: _*))).show

// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |UDF(named_struct(NamePlaceholder, a, NamePlaceholder, b, NamePlaceholder, c))|
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |                                                                    [a, b, c]|
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Values can be accessed by name using `Row.getAs` method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple working example:

Input Data:

```
+-----+---+--------+
| NAME|AGE|CATEGORY|
+-----+---+--------+
|  RIO| 35|     FIN|
|  TOM| 90|     ACC|
|KEVIN| 32|        |
| STEF| 22|     OPS|
+-----+---+--------+
```

//Define category list and UDF

```
val categoryList = List("FIN","ACC")    
def mapCategoryUDF(ls: List[String]) = udf[Boolean,Row]((x: Row) => if (!ls.contains(x.getAs("CATEGORY"))) false else true)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{struct}
df.withColumn("errorField",mapCategoryUDF(categoryList)(struct("*"))).show()
```

Result should look like this:

```
+-----+---+--------+----------+
| NAME|AGE|CATEGORY|errorField|
+-----+---+--------+----------+
|  RIO| 35|     FIN|      true|
|  TOM| 90|     ACC|      true|
|KEVIN| 32|        |     false|
| STEF| 22|     OPS|     false|
+-----+---+--------+----------+
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Can you may be write the long version of the udf with output etc. please? I have to get around all the shorthand.