# pyspark getting the field names of a a struct datatype inside a udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to pass multiple columns to a `udf` as a `StructType` (using `pyspark.sql.functions.struct()`).

Inside this `udf` I want to get the fields of the struct column that I passed as a `list`, so that I can iterate over the passed columns for every row.

Basically I am looking for a pyspark version of the scala code provided in this answer - [Spark - pass full row to a udf and then get column name inside udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50474698/spark-pass-full-row-to-a-udf-and-then-get-column-name-inside-udf?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same method as on the post you linked, i.e. by using a [`pyspark.sql.Row`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row). But instead of `.schema.fieldNames`, you can use [`.asDict()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row.asDict) to convert the `Row` into a dictionary.

For example, here is a way to iterate over the column names *and* values simultaneously:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct, udf

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3)], ["a", "b", "c"])
f = udf(lambda row: "; ".join(["=".join(map(str, [k,v])) for k, v in row.asDict().items()]))
df.select(f(struct(*df.columns)).alias("myUdfOutput")).show()
#+-------------+
#|  myUdfOutput|
#+-------------+
#|a=1; c=3; b=2|
#+-------------+
```

---

An alternative would be to build a `MapType()` of column name to value, and pass this to your `udf`.

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit

f2 = udf(lambda row: "; ".join(["=".join(map(str, [k,v])) for k, v in row.items()]))
df.select(
    f2(
        create_map(
            *chain.from_iterable([(lit(c), col(c)) for c in df.columns])
        )
    ).alias("myNewUdfOutput")
).show()
#+--------------+
#|myNewUdfOutput|
#+--------------+
#| a=1; c=3; b=2|
#+--------------+
```

This second method is arguably unnecessarily complicated, so the first option is the recommended approach.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the .asDict() option and it worked. I will also try the alternative solution